# MS Access VBA to Move PDF's to Folders specified in record set

Tags: vba, database, file, ms-access, pdf

To people who know this I would think should be very simple. I have an Access table listing PDF names in a specific folder, and the Agents to which they are linked by a unique reference number. There are many PDF's to one Agent.

What I would like to do is have a user press a button on a form, and the PDF's get copied to the corresponding agents folder. My code is a bit of a mish mash, I have cobbled it together from code fragments we had here and bits of google fu.

It creates the folders, but leaves some of them empty. It also moves only one PDF per agent across. I'm guessing I need a loop, but I have no idea where to put one.

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Dim intCurrPos As Integer, intNextPos As Integer, intLength As Integer
Dim strSlash As String, strFolder As String, strRSFolder As String
Dim fs, cf, x
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
On Error GoTo Err_CreateFolder

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_PDF_Agent", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
On Error Resume Next

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strSlash = "\"
intCurrPos = 4
strFolder = CurrentProject.Path
intLength = Len(strFolder)

    If intLength > 3 Then
        Do
            intNextPos = InStr(intCurrPos, strFolder, strSlash)
            intCurrPos = intNextPos + 1
                If intNextPos > 0 Then
                   If fs.FOLDEREXISTS(Left(strFolder, intNextPos - 1)) = False Then
                      Set cf = fs.CreateFolder(Left(strFolder, intNextPos - 1))
                   End If
                Else
                   If fs.FOLDEREXISTS(Left(strFolder, intLength)) = False Then
                      Set cf = fs.CreateFolder(Left(strFolder, intLength))
                   End If
                End If
        Loop Until (intNextPos = 0)
    End If

    While Not rs.EOF
        strRSFolder = strFolder & "\" & rs!Agent
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            If fs.FOLDEREXISTS(strRSFolder) = True Then
               'MsgBox "'" & strRSFolder & "' already exists!"
            Else
               Set cf = fs.CreateFolder(strRSFolder) & "\"
                   If fs.FOLDEREXISTS(strRSFolder) = True Then
                   fs.CopyFile CurrentProject.Path & "\" & rs!FullName, _
                    (strRSFolder) & "\" & rs!FullName

                   Else
                      'MsgBox "'" & strRSFolder & "' was not successfully created!"
                   End If
            End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    MsgBox "Done"

    Exit Sub
```

Any pointers anyone can give would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on what your objective is but if you are wanting to transfer all the PDFs to a particular agent's folder, assuming the full UNC location of the PDFs' initial and destination paths are stored in a table in two columns, you could loop through those records in the table, use the VB Name function and pass the source and destination folder strings to the function from the recordset. Here's some pseudo code (Field1 is the source UNC location and Field2 is the destination UNC location):

```
Do While Not Recordset.EOF
    Name Recordset!Field1 AS Recordset!Field2
Recordset.MoveNext
Loop
```